# setting custom errors inside Route Groups in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Today, I was exploring Codeigniter 4 and I got stuck while setting custom 404 error inside route group.

```
$routes->group('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->add('page', 'Welcome::index');
    $routes->set404Override(function () {
        echo 'Not Found admin';
    });
});

$routes->group('user', function ($routes) {
    $routes->add('page', 'Welcome::index');
    $routes->set404Override(function () {
        echo 'Not Found user';
    });
});
```

When I hit /admin/123 url, I should get 'Not Found admin'. Instead what I am getting is 'Not found user'. Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong or is it a bug? How can I manage to get separate 404 errors based on Route Groups.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got the answer from Codeigniter Forum by iRedds. This can be done by adding the last route in route group as follows:

```
$routes->add('(:any)', function() {
 return 'Not Found ....';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of separate 404 overrides per route group. You're just calling the same method from the same object twice, which means your second call is just overwriting the first.

`$routes` is an instance of the RouteCollection class:

```
// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes(true);
```

This class has a property that stores the closure for a 404 override:

```
/**
 * A callable that will be shown
 * when the route cannot be matched.
 *
 * @var string|Closure
 */
protected $override404;
```

Every time you call `set404Override`, you're just overwriting that same property.

If you want case-by-case handling of 404s, then I suggest you make a Controller to handle such a task and point `$routes->set404Override` to that Controller.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: @AlbertGeorge I can start pointing you in the right direction... Controllers have access to the IncomingRequest class (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html); this class has a very useful method called `getPath` (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#getPath) which you could use to inspect what URI actually 404'd and respond accordingly.